# If elem SlideDown .. then slideUp jquery

Tags: jquery, slidedown, slideup

i have this jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".C_bmiShowTableWord").click(function () {
    $(".C_bmiShowTable").slideDown();
  });
});
```

if i click the `C_bmiShowTableWord` it will slide down `C_bmiShowTable`

i want to make it if i click the `C_bmiShowTableWord` and `C_bmiShowTable` already been slide down , then slide it up .. and vice ^_^

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".C_bmiShowTableWord").click(function () {
    $(".C_bmiShowTable").slideToggle();
  });
});
```

Just use [slideToggle](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) instead.